# Unable to ping to machine.local but can ping machine

Tags: networking

My ubuntu machine name is `machine`. I am able to do successfully `ping machine`, but when I do `ping machine.local`, it doesn't resolve machine.local and gives message

`ping: machine.local: Name or service not known`

How should I fix this?

Thnaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from what @mikhail-zakharov said, I found out that apparently, avahi service was down and I needed to restart. Article at [smallbusiness.chron.com/resolving-local-ubuntu-38861.html](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/resolving-local-ubuntu-38861.html) and https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3258021.

Answer (score 1):

Configure and start MDNS service or add appropriate records to your DNS server or add an antry to your /etc/hosts file

Comment: Thanks. I added and it didn't work. Apparently, avahi service was down and I needed to restart. Article at https://smallbusiness.chron.com/resolving-local-ubuntu-38861.html and https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3258021.